# How can I create secure CRUD operation using MERN stack

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, hash, mern

I'm new to MERN stack and I did CRUD operation. I want to hash the password upon creation of new user, since I'm getting an error after creating a new user and trying to login "Invalid credentials" since the new user has been created with the password plain text and my registration compares the password with the hashed one

My create new user code:

exports.create = (req, res) => {

```
if(!req.body.name || !req.body.email || !req.body.password) {
     return res.status(400).send({
         message: "Name, Email and Password can not be empty"
     });
}

const user = new User({
    name: req.body.name.trim(),
    email: req.body.email.trim(),
    password: req.body.password.trim()
});

user.save()
.then(data => {
    const user = usersSerializer(data)
    res.send(user);
}).catch(err => {
    res.status(500).send({
        message: err.message || "Some error occurred while creating the User."
    });
});
```

};

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must hash the user's password before storing it in the database. Do something like this.

```
router.post(
'/register',
[
    check('email', 'Uncorrectly e-mail').isEmail(),
    check('password', 'Uncorrectly password').isLength({ min: 6 })
],
async (req, res) => {
try {
    const errors = validationResult(req)
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
        return res.status(400).json ({
            errors: errors.array(),
            message: 'Incorrect registration data'
        })
    }
    console.log(req.body)
    const { email, password, firstName, lastName } = req.body


    const candidate = await User.findOne({ email })

    if (candidate) {
        return res.status(400).json({ message: 'User already exist' })
    }


    const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password,12)
    const user = new User ({email, password: hashedPassword, firstName, lastName})
    await user.save()

    res.status(201).json({ message: 'New user created' })


} catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json ({ message: 'ERROR' })
}
```

})